# Fastlane-deliver - set the "Volume Purchase Program" option

Tags: ios, automation, app-store-connect, fastlane-deliver

I've been googling a lot but could not find any instruction for passing the "Volume Purchase Program" option when submitting an iOS app to iTunesConnect using fastlane-deliver.

Does anyone know if it's even possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it from fast-lane itself.

Here is the options file of fastlane project.

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/deliver/lib/deliver/options.rb

As you can "not" see, there is no field to change B2B option there. Unfortunately, it seems you should manually change this.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has provided an option to add a volume purchase program.
Check below link, it may help you out.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/B2B.html